# How can I change (locally) a hyperlink on a site to point to a different location? Opera, Windows XP

Tags: windows, opera, domain, redirection, url

How can I change all instances of a hyperlink pointing to, say, domain_address_a, to point to domain_address_b (still a string address, not an IP address, both URLs in this case belong to the same site) in Windows globally (akin to .hosts) or inside Opera (like a javascript browser plugin)? I'm only talking about a client-side change, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Redirector for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/) lets you do all kinds of URL-based redirections, so people who use it and have the same problem/situation can just download [Redirector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/) and stop reading this.

For Opera, try this [UserScript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/54870).

I personally use Opera too, and a Windows freeware called HandyCache to handle redirections, adblocking, proxy forwarding etc. (its site is in Russian but you can change the interface to English and other languages after downloading... if you are interested I can teach you how to use it). Some examples of redirections I've created are one for accessing the mobile version of Blogspot blogs automatically and another one for opening just the pictures instead of complete imgur pages. Again, all that is possible with Firefox extensions as well.

Comment: Thank you! Russian is my first language, so it's actually easier for me this way.

Comment: Nice! Its forums are very useful, so check them out too. :) Try this on HandyCache (copy everything and use the "paste from clipboard option" on the list of Redirect options): `#5#~#True#~#^((www)?.*blogspot\.com\/)$|^(http:\/\/\w+.*blogspot\.com.*html)$#~#$1?m=1#~#True#~#True`