# Make URL call a different URL on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, url, hosts, remapping

If I have a URL such as:

```
http://localhost:12345/foo
```

Is it possible to make this URL actually call a different URL and return that content? Such as say:

```
http://www.google.com
```

I would also like any sub-folders to then map in the same way:

```
http://localhost:12345/foo               > http://www.google.com
http://localhost:12345/foo/bar           > http://www.google.com/bar
http://localhost:12345/foo/bar/baz.jpg   > http://www.google.com/bar/baz.jpg
```

I've tried doing this using the hosts file, but this seems to only be for IP addresses, whereas I'm interested in routing this URL path to another path.

Comment: Well you have to remember that even www.google.co.uk is just an A record for an IP address.. so firstly I wouldn't touch localhost because you'll cause yourself all sorts of problems however if you wanted to use another alias the host file is the way to. For example if I ping www.google.com grab the IP and set in my host file mygoogle to that IP it will direct mygoogle to google.com. Not sure if this is exactly what you want so didn't put as an answer

Comment: You need a reverse proxy to do that. Apache HTTPd and nginx are popular choices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change (locally) a hyperlink on a site to point to a different location? Opera, Windows XP](http://superuser.com/questions/358632/how-can-i-change-locally-a-hyperlink-on-a-site-to-point-to-a-different-locatio), also see [How can I create shorter URLs to sites on my computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/408516/how-can-i-create-shorter-urls-to-sites-on-my-computer)